# PHP: Call a method on a returned class

Tags: php, dry, php4, syntactic-sugar, simplification

I have a method which returns a class and want to call a method on it. Instead of

```
$theClass = $this->getClass();
$theClass->foo();
```

I would like to write

```
$this->getClass()->foo();
```

Is there a syntax for this as of PHP4?

This works:

```
$this->{$this->getClassName()}->foo();
```

But I would like to manipulate the class beforehand (I do this now in getClass()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it won't work in PHP4, this feature has been bettered in PHP5. I wonder why are you still using PHP4 :)

Comment: @Carson Myers: yeah it is strange people still using php4 :(

Comment: I'm sad, too, but my company still uses PHP4 (and Apache 1.3 - and Kernel 2.4). ;-)

Maybe someone else can come up with some fancy construct that allows me to write my statement in one line?

Comment: you're better off writing it on two lines. Just do one thing per line.